# Cant access ssh on first attempt

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I've suddenly started having problems connecting to my ubuntu 12.04 server through ssh.

When i try to login with ssh user@host nothing happends.
If i open up another terminal while the first is still hanging i can acces the ssh just fine.

I've tried passing the -v flag but the first terminal still hangs. Only the second respons.

My last succesfull ssh login was a couple of days ago and since no changes have been made to the server so i cant seem to figure out why i all of a sudden cant connect.

Does anyone have an idea of whats going on?

This is what the -v flag tells me on succesfull login:

```
ug1: Host 'host.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Administrator/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Administrator/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ubuntu@host.com's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

Comment: Is the name of your host "root"?

Comment: Paste the log with -v flag.

Comment: @GeoSword No that was just a type from my side.

Comment: Do you have encrypted home directories?

Comment: @MadHatter No. My homedirectorys is just like they where when i installed ubuntu.

Comment: I have no idea what ubuntu's defaults are, and therefore repeat my question.

Comment: Im sorry, but neither do i. Is there someway i can check it?

Comment: Can you please post up the result of telnet host 22 without any other ssh connections open to that host.

Comment: @GeoSword telnet host.com:22 gives me respond below.
Connecting To host.com:22...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed

Comment: Not `telnet host.com:22`, `telnet host.com 22`; space, not colon.

Comment: @MadHatter that changes the respond a bit. SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a DNS issue on the client side. Check to see if your all the DNS servers that your using on the computer your SSHing from resolve your the host your trying to access. On a unix like system nameservers will probably be in /etc/resolv.conf. You can then see if they answer for your host using the host command.

> host your.host.com your.dns.server.com

If it doesn't respond with the IP of your server you can either change the nameservers your using (how to do this depends on what system your on) or by adding a line to your hosts file so that your.host.com always resolves to the same address without querying a nameserver. For unix like systems this would be /etc/hosts, and you can add a line that looks something like:

> 111.111.111.111   your.host.com

Answer (score 0):

As per your `telnet` response your port 22 is getting forward at port 23 Check your `network/firewall setting`  for this and.Logs are normal.

Comment: You misread what the OP typed.

Comment: opps sorry for that then ai have to change the answer.